# Impossible to take a picture from the app

Tags: android, image, android-camera-intent

I'm using different tab, almost the sames. 
In my app, I want to take picture with the camera with this code

```
  public void takePicture(View v) {
    imageFilePath = file_path + "/" + "Photo_" + idFiche + ".png";
    File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

       //blablabla
    }
}
```

It works well for some tab, but with others, it's impossible to click on the activation button of the photo app to save the picture, as indicated in below picture with the red border.
[image]

I think the camera app is wrong, even if I can take picture from the device directly (not from my app), but how to solve it? Can I delete the picture app and use another app with the same code? Or launch a specific app through new intent???

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I think the camera app is wrong

Most likely. Many camera apps seem to go through little testing of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

> how to solve it?

Stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use the camera APIs directly or through a third-party library.

> Can I delete the picture app

If by "the picture app", you mean "the camera app", it is likely that the camera app is pre-installed and cannot be uninstalled. Plus, the user may not appreciate you attempting to uninstall their camera app.

> and use another app with the same code?

Your code will already give the user a choice of camera apps, if there is more than one that supports `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` installed on the device.

> Or launch a specific app through new intent?

It is highly unlikely that your desired "specific app" exists on the device.

Comment: hi, I'm just testing with Open Camera as another picture app, and I had the same problem with a message "impossible to register the picture" (my traduction may be not perfect). So the truth is out there :). I will try with the camera APIs

Comment: @FlorentBreton: I do not know what `file_path` is, but Open Camera may not have rights to write there.

Comment: file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_folder";  all permission are already available

Comment: @FlorentBreton: "all permission are already available" -- it does not matter if your app has permission. What matters is if Open Camera has permission (and, also, whether the directory exists).

Comment: I found where the problem came from. The file_path was not created with certain tab. When I created it directly in the sdcard, everything goes right. I have to find why it happens like that, but you help me a lot in the reflection. Thanks